# Java Show Strike Line on Methods

Tags: java, date, deprecated

Why does it show strike line on `getDate()`, `getMonth()` and `getYear()`. These methods are used to get current date, month and year but I don't know why  it shows strike on these methods.

Code:

```
public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int days;
        int month;
        int year;

        days = 24;
        month = 10;
        year = 1994;

        System.out.println("Date of Birth: " + days + "/" + month + "/" + year);

        Date d = new Date();

        int t = d.getDate();
        int x = d.getMonth() + 1;
        int f = d.getYear() + 1900;

        System.out.println("Current Date: " + t + "/" + x + "/" + f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDEs like Eclipse would strike the methods if they are deprecated, meaning they're not recommended for use because there is a better alternative. See the [Javadocs of `getDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate--):

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.

Using `Calendar` methods:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Comment: what is the mean of getInstance();

Answer (score 2):

That's becuase they're deprecated. If you set the @deprecated in the info above a function, it'll strike methods over in most IDE's.

These specific functions are deprecated because the newer [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is a better option.

Comment: @ddmps how to use Calendar at the place of these methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        int days;
    int month;
    int year;

      days=24;
      month=10;         
      year=1994;

        System.out.println("Date of Birth: "+days+ "/" +month+ "/" +year);

        LocalDate dd = LocalDate.of(year, month, days);

    System.out.println("Current Date: " + dd);
    System.out.println("Month: " + dd.getMonth());
    System.out.println("Day: " + dd.getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println("Year: " + dd.getYear());

    //If you would add year
    LocalDate newYear = dd.plusYears(10);
    System.out.println("New Date: " + newYear);
```

This is output:

> Date of Birth: 24/10/1994
>
> Current Date: 1994-10-24
>
> Month: OCTOBER
>
> Day: 24
>
> Year: 1994
>
> New Date: 2004-10-24